# Google Analytics: _setSiteSpeedSampleRate generating two GIF requests

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have been immersing myself in some intricacies of Google Analytics, and have come across some behaviour I wanted to make sure I understood.

I have increased my site speed sample rate to 100% (low traffic site - currently nothing reported for site speed at all) in the usual manner for ga.js:

```
_gaq.push(['_setSiteSpeedSampleRate', 100]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

When looking at network activity, I'm now seeing two GIF requests to google instead of just one.

Comparing the requests it looks like the only notable difference is the **utmt** and **utmcs** params.  Everything else looks the same (or close enough).

This page https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsTrackingOverview#gifParameters indicate to me that those parameters are required to record the timing event, but I can't find a confirmation that two requests should be sent.

I'm guessing the first request is to track the pageview, and the second to track the timing event.

My question(s) are mostly for clarification:

1. Is this expected behaviour? (at the moment I'm assuming it is)
2. Since the second request for site speed has the same values as the page tracking request, will that result in doubling up of stat counts? (I'm assuming not, otherwise the default 1% sample rate would be giving false positives)
3. Why have two requests at all?  Since site speed is now on by default, and the event request includes the same info as the pageview request, couldn't both sets of information be extrapolated from a single request?

Comment: Did you find an explanation about this. I am seeing the same behaviour, and I also don't understand why are two requests needed.

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that _setSiteSpeeedSampleRate can be set betweeen 0 and 10 with 10 being the max value which in turn produces the most accurate  site speed report.  Google restricts the site speed collection hits for a single web property to either 1% of visitors or 10,000 hits per day (whichever is larger).  The effect of _setSite Speed Sample Rate only affects the calling page.  Set your sample rate to 10 for pages that are more important and then down around 0 for less important pages if you are worried about staying below the daily threshold.

Also, once ga.js is called by a website running GA tracking code, it is cached by the visitors browser and subsequently available for all following page views.  Meaning if someone visits my website when they wake up in the morning (unlikely LOL but...)  and then they visit your website, the ga.js is already in their cache and their browser shouldn't even need to call the function thanks to the previous site they visited having GA tracking code which is exactly the same as all GA _trackPageview calls.

The call of the JS routine _trackPageview is sort of like the engine that powers the rest of GA functionality, with it's .js file being 18KB in size and necessary for each page...  I was worried about the affect upon load time of my pages.  But as it turns out once it is called, it is cached by the visitors browser and subsequently available for all following page views.  Since this file is exactly the same for all Google Analytics accounts alike, it most likely won't need to be called if your visitor has previously visited another website equipped with GA tracking code.  Once it is loaded into the cache of a web user, the ga.js file no longer needs to be requested.

I wouldn't think you should be having two simultaneous requests sent as you ask unless you are actively coding and testing new code OR are not running it from a live server.  Once you upload your source files of your site to your domain, I wouldn't expect there to be a repeated call to the _trackPageview after it is cached.

Since you ramped your sampleRate up to 100 when it is only supposed to go up to 10 max (or at least unless this has been changed recently).  Id guess that your utmcs is probably being hyper sampled and and the utmt would then possibly be treated as a page if 100 is not an acceptable arg for the sampleRate, but that's just a guess based on reading over the entry provided in the link you gave.